# How do I store a BIGINT in MySQL using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, pdo

I know this question has been asked more than once here, but I couldn't find a solution.

We are using a database where we are storing the facebook id as a BIGINT(20).

```
create table users(
     fb_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
     user_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT uk_name unique (user_name), 
     CONSTRAINT pk_fb_id primary key (fb_id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

But the PDO engine of PHP can insert only the max integer value of PHP, i.e. 2147483647.

```
$stmt->bindParam(':fb_id', $this->fb_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

This, I understand, is quite obvious since we are limited by the maximum value of integer in PHP. I tried to use the string -

```
$stmt->bindParam(':fb_id', $this->fb_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

but still it doesn't work.

I want to know if there could be a workaround to store it as bigint.

Comment: What about using `PDO::PARAM_INT` but setting the value to a string with a really big number? `"892347932075913"`

Comment: If I use `PDO::PARAM_INT` then the `large string` gets reduced to `2147483647`, the maximum allowed value.

Comment: `PDO::PARAM_STR` with the value as a `large string` doesn't work either? I have no idea then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We are using a database where we are storing the facebook id as a BIGINT(20).

Why oh why are you doing that?

I think general consensus is that Facebook ids should not be saved as numeric types, but as strings instead. Saving them as something numeric does not yield any advantages whatsoever – but several disadvantages.

Comment: We had to store the facebook id as strings to resolve the issue.

But I would really like to know what are the disadvantages, for my own knowledge. Could you please shed some light on it?

Comment: There’s several problems that can easily occur, f.e. your database driver in fact returning them as numeric values, that will get casted to a float in PHP, which as you might know comes with an immanent precision loss (so your float number ends up something different then the actual user id value was), etc.

Comment: I've read that saving the Facebook Id's as big_int's will speed up comparison functions  in SQL, which I always thought to be untrue. I've always believed If the value is huge and you have a lot of rows, tough tomatoes-You will have to get creative with optimizing your queries, accept the fact that saving as a big_int won't offer any advantages whatsoever. This above answer confirmed my suspicion that saving as a string is the best practice.