# MySQL stores a different number when saving Facebook Session ID

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, prepared-statement

when my query works but when trying to save `provider_id` I get a differnt number in the database.

The type of the field is `INT`. It does not work (different numbers) unless I try to change the type of field to a `VARCHAR`

```
    /* prepare query */
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `users`(`first_name`, 
                                `last_name`, 
                                `gender`, 
                                `username`, 
                                `profile_picture`, 
                                `provider`, 
                                `provider_id`, 
                                `provider_username`,
                                `provider_profile`, 
                                `last_login`, 
                                `created_date`, 
                                `ip_address`) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW(), INET_ATON(?))'; 

/* Prepare an insert statement */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

if($stmt){
 $stmt->bind_param("ssssssisss", $user['first_name'], 
                                 $user['last_name'], 
                                 $user['gender'], 
                                 $user['username'], 
                                 $user['link'], 
                                 $user['provider'],
                                 $user['id'], 
                                 $user['username'], 
                                 $user['link'],                                     
                                 $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Correct me if i'm wrong I though it was a better idea to save as an `INT`

I get strange negative number:

```
-502711531
```

Comment: Try using `intval($user['id'])` instead of just `$user['id']` and let me know the result

Comment: What is the *actual* ID value you are trying to insert?

Comment: its an id from facebook user session @user2864740

Comment: @jenny Well, what *is* the value? Include it in the post.

Comment: @user2864740 it's `100007810775829`

Comment: @jenny Oh, good, *now* we are getting somewhere. [What is the *range* of the `INT` type in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)? Anyway, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938384/how-do-i-store-a-bigint-in-mysql-using-pdo as it's not strictly a MySQL issue (but also relates to PDO and PHP integer sizes and silly nonsense implicit conversions).

Comment: @user2864740 its `int(20)` shouldnt it be enough? i tried `BIGINT` also

Comment: @jenny `INT(1)` and `INT(99)` have the *same range*, as explained in the documentation. Also, due to MYSQLI/PHP driver issues wrt numeric types an conversions, BIGINT can be problematic (try to bind to BIGINT with the `s` - not `i` - hint, although that might lead to conversions on reading. Or, simply use a CHAR field and treat the Session ID as an *opaque non-numeric identifier*.

Comment: so strange  I changed to `s` now its `2147483647` not negative number anymore,

Comment: @jenny That (2147483647) is the maximum size of a MySQL INT field. When `i` was used the conversion happened *in* PHP (which was effectively `(int)ID` and overflowed), with `s` it happens *in* MySQL where it just "capped out" but didn't overflow. If you switch to a BIGINT in MySQL with `s` then, it should work. However, to avoid similar (unexpected) conversion issues, consider using a CHAR field anyway.

Comment: it worked with BIGINT(99) is `99` fine? thanks a lot thats one thing I didnt tried. Oh so you are saying it would be better if I go with VARCHAR?

Comment: Remember: BIGINT(1) is the same as BIGINT(99), except for display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core problem is that there is *loss* of range during implicit conversions.

When `i` is used as the mysqli binding hint it effectively does `(int)value`. In a 32-bit system the Session ID exceeds the maximum size of the PHP integer and *overflows*: `(int)"100007810775829" -> -502711531`.

When `s` is used, then mysqli does not do this conversion, but passes the value off directly to MySQL (as a string). In this case MySQL silently stores the [maximum value it can](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) for the field, which is `2147483647` for an INT column.

Thus, using `s` *with* BIGINT field would "work" because:

1. mysqli does not try to coerce the value to an integer
2. MySQL BIGINT can store [-2<sup>63</sup>, 2<sup>63</sup>-1]

However, I *recommend* using a CHAR type instead. This is because the Session ID should be treated as an *opaque identifier* and *not* as a number - no math operations apply to it. In addition, simply using a CHAR may avoid silent implicit conversions in the future, such as when dealing with drivers which may incorrectly convert a BIGINT to an integer or float PHP value and thus (like this issue) result in loss of range or precision.

Comment: Was facing this issue once. I also changed the datatype from `int` to `bigint` and that worked. But didn't knew the reason. Well explained. +1.

Comment: @ParagTyagi Cool :) This problem has the extra fun of mysqli's internal handling.